# Cancelling the keypress [Enter] action on a Telerik RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, keypress, telerik-grid

I have a **Telerik Radgrid** containing all the valid usernames and passwords that can be used to unlock functionnalities on my web page.

The password is encrypted, so you have to click the row to decrypt and show the actual password. All usernames and passwords can be changed by an admin

When the admin presses [ENTER] to submit the new username/password combination (instead of pressing the submit button), the new combination is actually submitted (which is fine).

---

However, my problem is that, by default, the RadGrid selects the next row, which decrypts the password and lets you edit the username/password.

Ideally, pressing [ENTER] would only submit the username/password combination, not selecting any other row. If that's not possible, pressing [ENTER] should not do anything.

If have tried the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                
    function KeyPressed(sender, eventArgs) {
        if (eventArgs.get_keyCode() == 13) 
        {
            alert("Cancelling event");
            eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
        }
    }
</script>
```

The alert box is raised, but the [ENTER] event is not interrupted.

**Edit:** Note that the alert is for testing only!

I have also added this code to my RadGrid control to add KeyPress capture

```
    <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true" EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true" ClientEvents-OnKeyPress="KeyPressed" AllowKeyboardNavigation="true">
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
    </ClientSettings>
```

My question is: How can I interrupt the [ENTER] keypress event? Or modify its behavior?
Any hints will be appreciated

---

I am using VB.net on Visual Studio 2008.
I am using ASP.net version 2.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my javascript code to cancel an event on enterkey.

```
 function CheckKey() {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                CancelEvent();
            }
        }
 function CancelEvent() {
            var e = window.event;

            e.cancelBubble = true;
            e.returnValue = false;
            if (e.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
            }        
        }
```